# In ordinal regression cumulative link models, when to use scale effects (versus/with random intercepts)

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, interpretation, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

When fitting a cumulative link mixed model (clmm) using the `ordinal` package in `R` we have the option to provide random effects and scale effects. What I would like to understand is when to fit variables to these parameters? Specifically, in the case when you have multiple raters assessing multiple objects.

I'll use the example `wine` dataset provided with the `ordinal` package, where we have 9 judges assessing 8 bottles of wine for bitterness. As I understand;

- fitting judge as a random effect (intercept) in model will allow us to account for differences between judges in how critically they score (e.g. one judge might tend to assess all bottles of wine as more bitter than another judge). The model assumes that the means of all judges are normally distributed around the grand mean.
- fitting judge as a scale effect will allow us to account for differences in the variation of ratings within individual judges. In other words the level of discrimination that judges have towards bitterness (e.g. one judge might tend to rate all bottles of wine as equally bitter, whereas another judge provides ratings that range from 'not at all bitter' to 'very bitter').

In the code below, I've fitted models with just scale effects, just random effects, or both, and looked at how this may change the estimated influence of another independent variable 'temp' (temperature during wine production).

Looking at a descriptive summary of the data (see first figure below), we can see that judges differ in their mean rating (judge7 = ~ 30/100, judge1 = ~63/100), and in the spread of their scores (judge5 has a very narrow range of score, judge2 a very wide range). So perhaps we may consider adding judge as a random effect and scale effect?

Adding 'judge' as a random effect only slightly changes the estimated influence of 'temp' (from 2.3 to 2.7), perhaps because all judges rated all bottles of wine. However, adding judge as a scale parameter substantially reduces the estimated influence of 'contact' (from 2.3 to 1.1). Adding judge to both random and scale effects provides a similar estimate as with scale effect alone, however the model struggles to fit (iteration limits are reached when estimating random effects, and the condition number of the Hessian is inflated, SE is very small) so perhaps this is not good practice?

So, my questions are:

- Is my understanding above correct?
- In the example `wine` dataset, should 'judge' be fitted as a scale and/or random effect? Why or why not?
- Is this the correct use of the scale effect, or should it be applied to the fixed effects only (such as 'temp' as shown in https://rdrr.io/rforge/ordinal/f/inst/doc/clm_tutorial.pdf)
- In a dataset where each rater (judge) rated only a random sample of objects (bottles), would it make sense to fit rater and object as random effects (i.e. assuming the bitterness of bottles of wine was normally distributed about a grand mean)? The `ordinal` package doesn't provide for fitting a scale effect with more than one random effect.

The ranked order of scale effect is somewhat surprising to me, given the descriptive data. It appears from the model that only judge 2 provides a wider range of scores than judge 7?

```r
libs <- c("ggplot2", "ordinal")
for(lib in libs)
  suppressWarnings(library(lib, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE))
    
## Order judges from least to most critical
dat_wine <- wine |> 
  dplyr::mutate(judge = factor(judge, levels = c(7, 2, 9, 8, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1)))

## Descriptive summary (mean +/- SD) of judges ratings
ggplot(dat_wine, aes(judge, response)) + 
  # geom_violin() + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = \(x) mean_sdl(x, 1))
```

[image]

```r
## Fit models, with scale and/or random effects
mdls <- list(
  
  b = clm(   rating ~ temp, data = dat_wine, Hess = TRUE),
  s  = clm(  rating ~ temp, scale = ~ judge, data = dat_wine, Hess = TRUE),
  r  = clmm2(rating ~ temp, random = judge,  data = dat_wine, Hess = TRUE),
  sr = clmm2(rating ~ temp, scale = ~ judge, random = judge, data = dat_wine, Hess = TRUE),
  r2 = clmm( rating ~ temp + (1|judge) + (1|bottle), link = "probit", data = dat_wine, Hess = TRUE)
  
) |> suppressWarnings()

# lapply(mdls, summary)

dat_coef <- lapply(mdls, \(m) 
                   summary(m)$coefficients |> 
                     data.frame() |> 
                     tibble::rownames_to_column("term") 
) 

## Estimated location coefficients (fixed effects)
lapply(dat_coef, \(x) subset(x, term == "tempwarm")) |> 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "model") |> 
  knitr::kable(digits = 3)
```

| model | term | Estimate | Std..Error | z.value | Pr…z.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | tempwarm | 2.287 | 0.513 | 4.458 | 0.000 |
| s | tempwarm | 1.141 | 0.503 | 2.268 | 0.023 |
| r | tempwarm | 2.668 | 0.554 | 4.815 | 0.000 |
| sr | tempwarm | 1.141 | 0.003 | 347.740 | 0.000 |
| r2 | tempwarm | 1.700 | 0.434 | 3.921 | 0.000 |

```r
## Estimated scale coefficients
emmeans::ref_grid(mdls$s, mode = "scale") |> plot(type = "response") + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I have not seen "scaling" models for non-continuous outcomes do what you are proposing here. With continuous outcomes, yes (google mixed effects location-scale models - MELSM). But with categorical outcomes, the way it has been done mostly is to allow predictors to have different scaling factors (or unique thresholds) in terms of their relation to the outcome. This is what is described in the pdf you linked.